# Troubleshooting: removing empty lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, osx

I have a text file with a lot of blank lines that I want to remove like:

```
aaa

bbb


ccc
```

I would like to get:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

At the moment I am trying:

```
LANG=C sed -E '/^\n|^\r|^\r\n|^\n\r/d' file
```

I should say I am using OSX. I have tried quite a few things and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have already tried searching for \r character

Comment: @8bittree I searched everywhere to find an answer (most similar questions didn't help) but you managed to find one I didn't see. I have tried it and it worked. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file.txt
```